# How to implement logout functionality in react native?

Tags: react-native, logout, asyncstorage

As i'm trying to develop an app in react native , i want to implement logout functionality.Now i found a problem that for every user who is logging, the name,and details appearing in their profile is same for each user.I'm using asyncstorage for setting unique id.Now i'm trying to unset this session using 
`Asyncstorage.removeItem('key_uuid')`.Do i need to write this in a separate `js` file?I don't know actually  where to give this code in my project.Sorry can anybody help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple implementation, on login you need to save some logged in user information as to check weather a user is logged in or not.
You canprovide logout button anywhere in the app, and on clk of that you can clear your asyncStorage or remove only user info from storage.
And when user opens your app you can check user in asyncstorage.

Comment: Yeah i'm saving the unique id of each user. So it means that i don't need to write it on a separate `js` file right?

Comment: Yes, because you can access asyncstorage from abywhere in your app, it is good code practice that you separte your code according to your need.